# Issues when RTSP streaming from CCTV cameras over Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming, wireless-access-point, rtsp, cctv

I'm working on a project where we will be using UniFI [AC-HD](https://unifi-hd.ui.com/) and [AC-Pro](https://www.ui.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-pro/) access points to RTSP stream CCTV video. But we are having issues...

With the UniFI AC-Pro we are able to do two continues streams; each stream is 1080p about 5 Mbit/s. If we try with three; all streams collapse. And we are not able to get any usable video feed.

The AC-HD handles three streams, but if we add a fourth; the same thing happens - all streams collapse.

I'm having problems understanding exactly what is going on here; one theory was that each stream fully utilizes a MIMO channel. And that this is the reason why the AC-HD can handle one additional stream, compared with the AC-Pro.

All streams are on LAN, the CCTV server and access points are connected to a UniFi [US-16-150W](https://www.ui.com/unifi-switching/unifi-switch-16-150w/) switch.

Does anyone have any similar experiences with RTSP streaming over Wi-Fi? Or understand what is going on here?

**Further information:** We are testing primarily using 5Ghz, and all CCTV cameras are within two meters of the access point during our testing. The UniFi controller software seems to indicate that all cameras have a 72 Mbit connection.

The CCTV cameras supports 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz bands with 802.11 a/b/g/n standards. The specification is limited, I'll reach out to the manufacturer to get an answer to the number of spatial streams and channel width they support.

The access point is configured with 40 MHz channel width.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the average Wi-Fi Tx PHY rate each camera is getting. Let's say one of the cameras is so far away from the AP that it can only use the 5GHz minimum Tx rate of 6Mbps. Well, after typical Wi-Fi overhead, that'll only deliver ~4Mbps of usable throughput. So even a single camera would fail to deliver a 5Mbps stream under those conditions. If you want to support 4x 5Mbps streams (20Mbps aggregate), after overhead, you'll probably need to guarantee that each camera is getting a ~30Mbps average Tx PHY rate, otherwise there just won't be enough channel airtime to go around.

Comment: Also, it would help to know the detailed Wi-Fi specs of your cameras. It would be good to know the number of Tx spatial streams they support, and whether they support N, AC, or AX. If they only support N, do they even support 5GHz? If they support AC, do they support 80MHz-wide channels? Have you configured your UniFi APs for 80MHz-wide channels?

Comment: @Spiff Thanks for your comments. I have updated the question with more detailed information.

Comment: Those updates were super helpful, thanks. It eliminates a few of the initial possibilities. Knowing the number of spatial streams and channel width will be good. Getting just a 72Mbps PHY rate even at close range suggests only 1 spatial stream and only 20MHz channels. New question: is the actual RTP video stream unicast or multicast? If you've been trying multicast, switch to unicast.